# Re Open with Passcode when minimize app by Home key pressed with Jelly Bean,AppCompact API and ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, action, android-actionbar-compat

I have added passcode functionality with my app . It work fine. I have integrated and check splash screen if passcode created then ask passcode otherwse Main activity, It working good.
  But If I am in any activity then minimize app and reopen app then it should ask passcode then app normal functionality for home key means activity remain same than was minimize like Home key app minimize and reopen , it work.

I am working with AppCompact API and ActionBarActivity.

I need proper solution any if wrong. I am trying to implement with onStart method and onKeyDown() or onKeyUp()

```
Method try : 1
//------------------------------------------

        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onStart();
            if (isPasscode) {
                isPasscode = false;
                if (AppPreferences.getInstance().isPasscodeSaved()) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PasscodeActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(GlobalConst.VERIFY_PASSCODE, true);
                    startActivityForResult(intent,GlobalConst.REQUEST_PASSCODE);
                }
            }
        }  

//--------------------------------------
// Not calling on home key pressed
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME){
            Log.d("Test", "Home button pressed!");
          // Not calling on home key pressed
            isPasscode = true;  // If it will true on home pressed then I will implement all the activity but not happening .
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

//----------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------

Method try : 2: instead of onKeyDown , I have try to use onUserLeaveHint() method , It work but not properly . It call on home key pressed but call many time  after start method , Onactivity result method, activity refresh many time and also it property is interrupted with in coming call.

//--------------------------------------
        @Override
    protected void onUserLeaveHint() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onUserLeaveHint();
        if (!isPasscode) {
            isPasscode = true;   
        }
    } 
//---------------------------------------
```